# Manually add Seq[FormError] to a Form in Play 2.4 (Scala)

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I've got a normal `play.api.data.Form` in Play Framework 2.4. I do basic validation in my Action, but in my case, even if the user submitted data was syntactically correct, I may have to add errors depending on the result from an external service.

I get the error fields with error messages from a JSON object, e.g.:

```
{
    "name": [
        "Invalid name"
    ],
    "age": [
        "Invalid age",
        "Something else"
    ]
}
```

I can transform this JSON object into a `Seq[FormError]`:

```
val fields: Seq[(String, JsValue)] = jsObjErrorFields.fields
val formErrors: Seq[FormError] = fields map { case(key, jsValue) =>
    val messages: Seq[String] = jsValue.asOpt[Seq[String]] getOrElse Seq()
    FormError(key, messages)
}
```

I am aware of the `withError` method of the `Form` class, but it takes only one `FormError` argument:

```
def withError(error: FormError): Form[T] = this.copy(errors = errors :+ error, value = None)
```

I've got the feeling there must be a simple solution to this (map, for...?), but I cannot figure it out.

```
val formWithErrors = ...
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Action, instead of:

```
MyForm.bindFromRequest.fold( // ...
```

Keep form instance in a `val` and then `fold`:

```
val form = MyForm.bindFromRequest
form.fold( // ...
    formWithErrors => { /* ... */ },
    data => {
        // ...
        // Copy the form and apply the errors from JSON:
        val formWithErrors = form.copy(errors = formErrors)
        // ...
    }
)
```